# PHP: fetch_assoc() into array causing null values

Tags: php, json, mysqli, mariadb

I'm trying to fetch data from a MariaDB database of festivals and respective locations. When running:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()){}
```

and iterating over $row while outputting the values, I get data as it is in the database.
However, when storing each row like so:

```
while($row = $sth->fetch_assoc()){
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

And echoing the results as JSON (echo json_encode($results);)
I get this:

```
{"id":"0","name":null,"village":"0","startDate":"2019-01-16",
"endDate":"2019-01-23","message":null}
```

This is for an existing Linux server, which I do not manage (I'm using CPanel). PHP version is 5.4 and MariaDB 10.1.37.

So far, a lot of code samples on Stack Overflow and other websites are using 
    $results[] = $row;
for storing the results.
I'm returning to PHP after 3 years of Swift only programming... So I suspect this could be a simple issue to solve...

Thanks!

Comment: So what's the actual issue? That row might actually have null values for those columns. Without seeing the data, it's hard to tell.

Comment: For example the "name" and "message" columns all have strings inside them... when I iterate over $row, I can echo the output. when I store each $row in $results, I can't seem to get anything other than null... which is weird because it only happens with string values. Could it be a charset issue?

Comment: `var_dump($results)` what is the output, and can you provide the query you're running?

Comment: $sth = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM festivals");

Comment: var_dump works, all the data, including strings are there... what's happening? lol

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(6) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["name"]=>
    string(23) "Festas de Santo António"
    ["village"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["startDate"]=>
    string(10) "2019-01-16"
    ["endDate"]=>
    string(10) "2019-01-23"
    ["message"]=>
    string(115) "Uma vila com muito para descobrir, e tanto que fazer! Desfrute ao máximo da 28ª edição das Festas de Santo António!"
  }
  [1]=> ....

}

Comment: Any suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score -1):

May be I'm bit too late for answering this question, but it may help someone stuck with this issue. Recently I faced a similar issue and it took me 3 days to understand that it is an issue with the utf-8 characters. Data stored in database are perfectly fine. But when it comes to return it via json_encode(), it shows no data at all as json_encode only supports utf-8 data([reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)).

For your case the following method should work-

```
foreach ($results as &$r) {
    $r['name'] = utf8_encode($r['name']);
    //same for all other items
}
```